# display individual columns from sql result in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm coding a simple application using c# asp.net. I'm getting the averages of columns. How can I get the individual values from the result and display it in a new label (`label1`, `label2`, `label3`....)?

I tried `ExecuteScalar().ToString();` but it returns only the first column.

Below is my code:

```
SqlConnection con;
con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\STATDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
string result = "SELECT AVG(p_tan) AS p_tang, AVG(e_tan) AS e_tang, AVG(p_rel) AS p_reli FROM statistics";
SqlCommand showresult = new SqlCommand(result, con);
con.Open();

Label1.Text = showresult.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
//Label2.Text = p_tang
//Label3.Text = e_tang
//Label4.Text = p_reli
con.Close();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `showresult.ExecuteReader()` and then iterate over the row to get the values

```
SqlDataReader reader=showresult.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
  Label1.Text= reader["p_tang"].ToString().Trim();
  Label2.Text= reader["e_tang"].ToString().Trim();
  Label3.Text= reader["p_reli"].ToString().Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteScalar` will only pull one value. You will need do either use a `DataReader` or `DataAdapter` to get multiple values from the database.